# How to know how long will take to execute pysaprk code

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to know how much time a code will take to finish? or an approximation

I am thinking something like when you are coping a file in windows, it says how much time is left, or for example when you download something, it tells you approximately how much time it will take

Is there a way to do this for a spark code? from something very simple like queries, to more complex code

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark themselves have considered implementing this but decided against it due to uncertainties in predicting the completion time of stragglers. See the discussion in this spark issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5216

So you will not get that information from spark. Instead you must implement your own estimation model.

Comment: Thanks, and you know how can I build a model to predict this?